# How is a texture map (based on a UV-Map) made

Tags: texturing, uv

I would like to know how the texture is mapped onto a UV-Map. What calculations do a program like substance painter (in my example)? I am asking because I got some problems with the texture and want to understand the underlying workflow of UV-Mapping and texture-mapping.

My Problem:
[image]

Eventhough the UV-Map looks fine, the texture is not correctly applied onto the mesh.

EDIT: After I found out that he UV-Map is the problem I tried to figure out where to set the seams. The Smart-UV project helped but of course the result is not that well. In order to understand the UV-Mapping I made another project with the same mesh. Now the Smart-UV project throws an error and I still won't get it unwrapped. It's just impossible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this the view from SP? Did you unwrap it in SP or Blender? Did you get a correct result while painting in SP, and a bad result in Blender, or both were bad result?

Comment: It's the view of SP, I don't know how to paint in Blender, will try later.

Comment: Might be off-topic if there isn't anything we can help with that is Blender-specific. Not enough of us are using SP to be much assistance here. Only thing I can suggest is to work out the UV projection from top on that road section, needs to be as straight on as possible, same for when it is painted, has to be done from top view I think.

Comment: Ok, it is definitely a blender issue. The problem is that the scale of the small faces between each big one are not propotional on the UV-map. Eventhough the scale is 1.0. Do you have a tip, how to scale each face in propotion to all other (on the UV-Map).

Comment: No, but you can make a copy of the file and test on that one by unwrapping it using Smart UV Project and then test if that has fixed your issue taking that one into SP to paint it. Your UV unwrapping needs to be redone, but I'd use a copy so that you can try different UV unwrapping schemes until you find you can paint it correctly.

Comment: Ok, so the smart UV unwrapping helped. I will have a lool if I can find a doc which describes how Blender does smart unwrapping